# Blocking on a SQL Insert Trigger and I cant figure out why

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a blocking detected on this section of code inside of a trigger:

```
DECLARE @AuditLog_Id int

SELECT @AuditLog_Id = AuditLog_Id 
FROM AuditLog AL (NOLOCK)
JOIN INSERTED I on AL.Appt_Id = I.Appt_Id
WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND,AL.Create_DtTm,@pCreate_DtTm) < 5
AND (AL.CreateUser_Id is null OR AL.CreateUser_Id = I.ModifyUser_Id)
AND AL.Action <> 'Create'
AND I.Status_Cd <> 'X'
```

What would be causing it? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. You are using scalar variables in a trigger. This is an immediate red flag that your trigger is unable to handle multiple row operations. Keep in mind that in sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. Also, that NOLOCK hint is a lot more sinister than most people realize. It is much more than dirty reads. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: As for the question at hand...we couldn't possibly tell you with only a query and no details at all.

Comment: OK. I didn't write this code and I'm tasked to fix it haha. 
Basically, this variable is then being used to either update if the @AuditLog_id > 0 or insert if it is not.
It's a CXPACKET Wait Type.

Comment: That just means it is busy executing a parallel plan.

Comment: I would consider rewriting this using a MERGE statement. That way it can be set based instead of scalar based and will perform either an update or an insert appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking" and what "detected" it on this piece of code?